# Dynamic custom UITableViewCell's height based on label text length

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, height

I'm noob in Xcode and Objective-C and I need help to make a dynamic table view cell's height based oh how many character in the label. So it will be like this:
if textLabel char is more than 10 it will resize the listHeight to 50
else if textLabel char is more than 20 it will resize the listHeight to 70
and so on...

This is how i code:

```
NSLong *text;

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *cellID = @"ChatTableViewCell";
   ChatTableViewCell *cell = (ChatTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

   if (cell == nil){
      NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ChatTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
      cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
   }

   Chat * chatObject;
   chatObject = [chatArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   cell.nameChat.text = chatObject.name;
   cell.messageChat.text = chatObject.message;
   cell.messageChat.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
   cell.messageChat.numberOfLines = 0;
   cell.dateChat.text = chatObject.time_entry;

   //attached foto
   NSString *setPhoto=chatObject.photo;
   [cell.imageChat setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/summit/www/media/user/photo/%@",setPhoto]]]]];
   cell.imageChat.layer.cornerRadius=cell.imageChat.frame.size.height /2;;
   cell.imageChat.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
   cell.imageChat.layer.borderWidth = 0;
   if (cell.imageChat.image==nil) {
      cell.imageChat.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"profile.png"];
   }

   text=[cell.messageChat.text length];
   return cell;
}
```

I'm trying this but not working:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   CGFloat height;
   if(text>=10){
      height=100;
   }
   else
      height=70;
   return height;
}
```

Please help me, i'm dying to do this @_@ Thanks in advance

Comment: You provide an example of constructing a cell but that does not define its height. Have you implemented the `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method? What have you tried? In addition do you really want the height to depend on the character count or are you trying to make sure that the cell is large enough to fit whatever text it contains?

Comment: I have the method but right now it only contain static value return 70;

Comment: I think you need to better define the rules you believe would calculate the correct cell height, even if you are not sure how to express them in code. Otherwise any answer here is just a guess at what you are trying to do. Your cells appear to contain many pieces of text, which of them should have an impact on the cell's height?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Fetch yourText for this row from your data source..
    NSString *yourText = [yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    CGSize labelWidth = CGSizeMake(300, CGFLOAT_MAX); // 300 is fixed width of label. You can change this value
    CGRect textRect = [visitorsPerRegion boundingRectWithSize:labelWidth options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"CenturyGothic" size:16.0]} context:nil];

    /* Here, you will have to use this requiredSize 
       and based on that, adjust height of your cell.
       I have added 10 on total required height of
       label and it will have 5 pixels of padding 
       on top and bottom. You can change this too. */

    int calculatedHeight = textRect.size.height+10;
    return (float)calculatedHeight;
}
```

Hope it works !!!

Comment: sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode: is depreciated in iOS 7. You should use boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context: instead.

Comment: THIS METHOD IS NOW DEPRECATED PLEASE USE `BOUND TO RECT` IN PLACE OF THE ABOVE

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to @Pratik's answer if you want to use dynamic text sizes would be something like a class method on the cell.

What we do at work is

```
+ (CGFloat)cellHeightForTitle:(NSString*)title inTableView:(UITableView*)tableView{
    UIFont *font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];
    NSString *text = title ?: @"test"; // Just some text
    CGFloat hotizontalPadding = 0; // account for other content for calculating width of the cell
    CGFloat desiredWidth = tableView.bounds.size.width - hotizontalPadding;
    NSAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: font}];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];

    label.attributedText = attributedText;
    label.numberOfLines = 0;
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    CGSize size = [label sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(desiredWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX)];

    font = nil;
    attributedText = nil;

    return size.height;
}
```